# Extend primitive type with additional state information for exceptional cases

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to extend an `int` variable by some status information, which is only very rarely used and most of the time its just the int value that counts. This is why i would like to avoid using a struct with additional boolean members.

Relevant additional properties would be maximal 5 to 6 additional properties for example NULL, UNDEFINED, NAN, MISSING of which only one can be true.

Ideas:

- An int pointer would be one way to do this for one additional property: nullptr is the one additional value the int variable can take. But in this case I could not have more exceptional states.
- Another option would be to use some magic values which I do not expect to be used such as `UNDEFINED = std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `MISSING = std::numeric_limits<int>::min()+1` and so on.

**Question**: Is there a better way to do this (which does require minimal additional memory)?

**Sub-Question**: Is there a good way to do this without using additional memory if I can decide if the value is of the exeptional cases during compile time?

Comment: What is the difference between undefined and missing?  AFAIK integers cannot be NAN.

Comment: Either you do as you say and use magic values, or you need more bits. You can't store additional information without using more memory one way or another. There are lots of options for where/how you store that extra information though.

Comment: @Mat yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @NathanOliver undefined would result in a NULL value during write to DB and missing would throw an error if the programmer tries to store the data in DB.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `std::any` or `std::optional` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best available alternative is not to use ints, but some other type – your suggestion to use a `int*` also falls in this category. This wrapper type can of course overload various operators for convenience of accessing the underlying integer value. Defining a new type (or leveraging existing standard library types) is optimal terms of memory, as you will probably only double the size of each integer (e.g. now you might have integer + enum (backed by int or smaller) + possibly padding). Depending on your integer size, even a pointer might have more memory overhead.

If only a few integers have an extra status AND those integers will not be copied or moved, then you could store the status externally, in a map from integer identity to status. I.e. we use the pointer to an integer object as key. Per integer with an extra status this map will have a much higher memory overhead than alternatives, but depending on your usage patterns this might be the most compact solution. Clearly, there is an opportunity for memory leaks here, so you should probably wrap your integers in a custom type that that removes any map entry on destruction. Roughly like this:

```
enum class IntStatus { IS_NAN, IS_MISSING };

class IntWithExternalStatus {
public:
  explicit IntWithExternalStatus(int x = 0) : m_value{x} {}
  explicit IntWithExternalStatus(IntStatus s) : m_value{} { s_status.insert({this, s}); }
  ~IntWithExternalStatus() { m_status.erase(this); }

  operator int& () { return m_value; }
  operator int  () const { return m_value; }
  bool is_valid() const { return s_status.find(this) == s_status.end(); }
  bool is_nan() const {
    auto it = s_status.find(this);
    return it != s_status.end() && it->second == IntStatus::IS_NAN;
  }
  bool is_missing() const {
    auto it = s_status.find(this);
    return it != s_status.end() && it->second == IntStatus::IS_MISSING;
  }
private:
  static std::unordered_map<IntWithExternalStatus const*, IntStatus> s_status;
  int m_value;
};
```

Maybe all of these extra types are unnecessary overcomplication. If you only have a few integer variables that need an extra status, creating a separate variable for the status may be easiest. E.g.:

```
int m_foo;
int m_bar;
IntStatus m_foo_status;
IntStatus m_bar_status;
```

Due to alignment issues, this might result in a more compact memory layout than defining a combined int-and-status object.

Using special values for your statuses is an easy solution without space overhead, but has a huge disadvantage: any arithmetic on those integers will erase the status and produce bogus values. You will need lots of runtime checks to prevent that, which would be best encapsulated in a separate type.

Regarding the compile-time subquestion, this depends on your definition of memory use. E.g. you could use template metaprogramming that selects an `int` or `InvalidInt` type depending on the compile-time value, where an InvalidInt is a kind of null-object pattern. However, this will generate specialized code for all instantiated templates. In particular, the code using your status-ints would also have to be templated. This could reduce total memory use if you have lots of status-ints at the same time that all have the same status, but is unlikely to be helpful in other scenarios.